# How to give a pitch at a conference?

Tags: conference, presentation

I am now attending (and presenting at) my first ever conference. I have already given the presentation of the paper. I received the following email:

> Dear X,
>
> your paper has been selected by the scientific committee as a nominee
> for the  best short paper award.
>
> Along with our congratulations, I would like to invite you for a 2-3
> minute short pitch on the last day of the Conference. After the
> attendants voting, the results of the single winner will be announced
> on the final part of the Conference.

I have only a very vague idea of what a pitch is. And I am unsure what I am supposed to say/show.

**Question 1:** What should (and should not) be included in the pitch?

**Question 2:** Do you have any tips to maximize my chance for winning?

**Question 3:** Is this a common thing at conferences?

Comment: Re. question 1: Have you asked the person that sent you the message?

Comment: Yes and I haven't got a response yet.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations. This is a win for you even if you are not the eventual winner.

I can't answer your three questions explicitly, but have this advice.

Say you're thrilled and honored by the nomination.

Three minutes is a very short time. The audience won't know you or your work. So tell them what your paper is about (not necessarily what you discovered).

Practice once or twice with a timer. But don't try to memorize your talk.

Search *elevator pitch*.

Comment: Yes, "elevator pitch" is the way to think about this. :)